# Is Stack Overflow the only Stack Exchange site that has a dark theme option? Why?

Tags: discussion, support, dark-mode

I checked 3 Stack Exchange sites other than Stack Overflow and I don't see the dark theme option. Why is that?

If it's still in beta, why not roll it out everywhere and get more feedback?

Comment: [Introducing Dark Mode (beta) for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/?_ga=2.224939996.798873470.1635435306-1536614470.1635435306): "For now, we have no plans to bring dark mode to the many sites across the Stack Exchange network. Many of the designs on our sites have been around long enough that converting them to dark mode would require redoing the artwork completely. We would prefer to avoid giving anyone across our network a substandard experience and we don’t want to change those elements without the input of these communities. "

Comment: If the company doesn't want to do this work, let users who are interested in having a dark theme create them and share them. They can start from SO's dark theme. It's not work going to be done from scratch.

Comment: To my knowledge they *are* working on it...it's just going to take time.

Comment: Because SO is special.

Comment: To back up what @Makoto said, here's what an employee [said on the subject of network-wide dark mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/#comment1239362_371305) - *"Dark mode across the whole network is something we're actively working towards, but there's still a lot of work to be done. We've been rolling out a lot of behind-the-scenes changes to network theming that users ([usually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367641)) don't notice to get us closer to our ideal theming state. I don't have any news or a concrete timeline at the moment"*

Comment: *let users who are interested in having a dark theme create them and share them.* That is where we have [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=dark+theme) for ... (I might or might not be affiliated with that site).

Comment: @rene. I meant take the best dark theme a user made and make it available in the site itself. Also, my guess is that most users do not know about Stack Apps. I have never gone to that site.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich There are extensions that can enable a dark mode for you on many sites such as Stylus (a fork of Stylish but without analytics). Having a dark mode would be nice across all SE sites but the link from Jeanne does showcase the problem in that there are *many* sites across SE and to introduce dark mode for them would need a redesign that may ultimately be fruitless; new sites are created and redesigning even a couple at a time may be outpaced by new communities being created. I would recommend suggest a dark mode on the meta SEs you care about, see how it is received by those.

Comment: Duplicate (cross-site): *[Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/)*. Related: *[Plans for dark mode for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359739)*, *[Are there any plans to roll out Dark Mode to non-English Stack Overflow sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351248/)*, and *[How do I enable dark mode on other sites in the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345886)*.

Comment: @Bender the Greatest I am not suggesting to do all the SE sites at the same time. Start with the most popular ones one at a time. A new community coming up has no consequence on other existing sites. If a new site comes up, does it affect SO's dark theme? I don't see how. Why do we need to care how it's received by the site's community? A dark theme now is becoming almost a standard. Most of the Windows apps I use have a dark theme.  Chrome Devtools has a dark theme. Azure Devops has a dark theme. If someone doesn't want to use the dark theme in an SE site, they don't have to.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich I guess that is a valid case for supporting dark themes for new communities, but at the same time each community of Stack Exchange is compartmentalized, to a point. See how the members of that community feel first and have *them* (including you if you are a member of that community) petition SE to support a dark theme for their community. Note: I'm not sure who designs the themes around a given community, whether that would be the community leaders or SE themselves. SO is a bit of an exception since it is **the** OG community Stack Exchange was built around.

Comment: Why on earth is the plan not to add it everywhere..?

Comment: It's taking quite a long time...

Comment: I was thinking we could Add an optional setting to allow using dark mode on a user level. It would also be in beta, so I wouldn't mind broken art work. SE is mostly utilitarian so utility trumps it all. And too much light hurts my eyes (personal xp)

Comment: I'm afraid to leave SO lands. The light is so bright out there ;) especially on the mobile web unable to shade it.